# subprocess.run() issues with mkdir

Tags: python, bash, scripting, subprocess

I am having trouble with `subprocess.run()`.

I try to create a new directory in a WindowsSubsystemForlinux1 WSL1 application inside W10.

The directory name shall be (for example):  `a0_998.0784269595375` (always 13 digits after the comma).
That set of digits comes as the output of a Python function.
What I have:

```py
def SMILEI(I):
    os.chdir("/home/velenos14/PICsims/github/SMILEI_correctTunnelBSIrate/Smilei/SIMRESULTS/GPs_trial_Xenon_noOAM")
    a0 = "%.13f" % a0_from_IntensityWcm2(I) # a0_from_IntensityWcm2() is a function
    subprocess.run(['dirname="a0_"', 'mkdir' '-p' '$dirname'], check=True, text=True) # PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'dirname="a0_'
```

What I am doing wrong?
The BASH commands (which work and do the job) are as following:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 15000; i++))
do
    index=$((i))
    a0=$(awk "NR==${index} { print \$2 }" Intensity_Wcm2_versus_a0_10_20_10_25_range.txt)
    dirname="a0_${a0}"
    mkdir -p $dirname
    cd $dirname
done
```

Comment: Why would you run mkdir as a subprocess instead of using the (far more efficient) built-in Python function that tells the operating system to create the directory immediately?

Comment: @velenos14 : You are trying to execute an external program named `dirname="a0_"`. The first argument in the array is the program to run.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you. I will use what you say. I just blindly wanted to write an entire BASH script (I have and works fine) using these ```subprocess.run()``` commands, having started from a search on Google: how to run an external program using Python. The BASH command to run my external program is ```mpirun -n 1 more_arguments```, but before this I was doing some pre-processing (change folder, create new folder in which results will appear, run the program, exit folder, create folder in which results appear, etc)

Comment: Anyhow -- `dirname="a0_${a0}" mkdir -p $dirname` as a single simple command doesn't even have your desired effect in bash (parameter expansions are done from shell variables; environment variables set for only the single command with leading key=value syntax aren't set in time to participate), and more than that, replacing `$dirname` with an actual directory name is a shell feature, so when you're directly executing a subprocess with no shell it never has a chance to happen in the first place.

Comment: If you do want to set an environment variable while a subprocess runs, by the way, there's a separate argument to all the subprocess functions that lets you pass in a dict of them.

Comment: I thought that if I enumerate many keywords in that list inside .run() it will run them, indeed in my .sh file these are 2 separate lines: ```dirname="a0_${a0}"``` and ```mkdir -p $dirname```

Comment: The _two separate lines_ part is critical. Try `a="one"; a=two echo "$a"` in shell -- you'll see it echoes `one` not `two`

Comment: Anyhow, `subprocess.run()` takes an argv -- an argument vector -- to use in running exactly one command; it's not one command per argument, it's one command with _all_ the arguments. (That's true even with `shell=True`, with the exception that the first argument in that case is passed to a shell as a script to run, so that shell then breaks it apart into multiple smaller commands; but without `shell=True` nothing like that ever happens)

Comment: (and to be clear, nothing in my above comment should be understood as advice that `shell=True` should be used; very much to the contrary, it adds complexity and security exposure that one is better off without).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see you want to pass the `dirname` argument as an environment variable to your `mkdir` subprocess.

Instead construct your `dirname` variable beforehand and pass it to `subprocess.run` like this:

```py
def SMILEI(I):
    os.chdir("/home/velenos14/PICsims/github/SMILEI_correctTunnelBSIrate/Smilei/SIMRESULTS/GPs_trial_Xenon_noOAM")
    dirname = "a0_%.13f" % a0_from_IntensityWcm2(I)
    subprocess.run(["mkdir", "-p", dirname], check=True, text=True)
```